# how to fill color to svg up to particular percent in android

Tags: android, svg, kotlin

I have an SVG like this, I need to fill it with any color only to the 50 Percent of this image, is it possible to do this in android, the `setColorFilter()` function applies the color to the entire image, is it possible to fill the image with a color only up to particular percent?

---

[image]

Comment: yes via a linearGradient.

Comment: I think you want to do something like a progressive view, It's possible with a simple custom view.